# Riemann Zeta Function at Real Values of the variable s

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

My question is: Is the Riemann Zeta function for real values of $s$ $( s = \sigma  + 0\,i)$ a monotone function of $\sigma \,$?

Comment: It is for $s>1$.

Comment: Thanks.                                                        Any formal proof? Is it decreasing?                                           Also, how about for 0 ≤ σ ≤ 1 and σ ≤ 0

Comment: It follow for $s>1$ pretty much straight from the definition: if $s>t$ then $n^{s}>n^t$ and therefore $$\frac{1}{n^{t}}>\frac1{n^s}$$ So it is decreasing

Comment: But it has zeros at the negative even integers, so it can't be monotone on the whole real line.

Comment: Thanks. How about when 0 < σ < 1 , is Zeta(σ) monotone decreasing?